# Robolectric.setupActivity() is deprecated in Android unit test

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric

I'm trying to use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) framework to run a simple `Unit` test, although I got that `Robolectric.setupActivity()` is deprecated.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityFragmentTest {

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }

    // Rest of Test
```

How can I solve that? Thanks for help in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use ActivityScenario, documetation is here: [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario)

```
try(ActivityScenario<MyActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity.class)) {
 scenario.onActivity(activity -> {
   assertThat(activity.getSomething()).isEqualTo("something");
 });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes I use this approach, but I tried to do something close with Robolectric library

Comment: @Zain Would you mind to share that? I have the same issue, I do not know what should I use instead of setupActivity(). Thanks

Comment: Hello @Hilal so far, I didn't find a solution with `Robolectric` but used `ActivityTestRule` approach to get an activity.